# What are the default fstab mount parameters in Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, fstab

I've accidentaly corrupted my `fstab` and cut the ends of lines. There are now `disk uid`, `mount point`, `filesystem` for root and swap, but the mount parameters are missing.

The system boots as `readonly`.

What are default fstab mount parameters in Debian for ext4 root and swap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your system's default mount options by simply entering `defaults` in the mount options section of `/etc/fstab`.  For instance:

```
UUID=1f894590-b69e-4113-9142-b189d3adb33f    /    ext4    defaults    1 1
```

Comment: And the defaults are defined in the kernel. You have a typo. Can you correct "/ext4" for "/    ext4"?.